# Adding elevation to layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom `listView` and the list item that i am using is a linear layout with couple of images and text. Now i want to make this list item a bit elevated just like the pic below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the background of each list item, you can use an xml drawable to achieve this effect:

`mydrawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/border_shadow"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

To adjust the shadow sizes, tweak the `left`, `right`, etc. in the second `item`. Use it in your `LinearLayout` for each item as `android:background="@drawable/mydrawable"`.

Comment: missing a "</layer-list>"