# Elevation and statelistanimator not working with recyclerview list items

Tags: android, material-design

I have a recyclerview which uses custom adapter and custom item layout.
I need to know what are the standards to apply elevation to recyclerview.
is elevation to be applied to recyclerview itself or to the item layout.

I also need to define statelistanimator to enable change in elevation when an item is selected. 
Where should I set the statelistanimator, to recyclerview or to the item layout?

I tried few ways to accomplish this. But nothing works when I run the application.
When I set the elevation and statelistanimator to item layout, I could see the elevation effect in the design time. But when I run the app, nothing appears in the list of items in recyclerview.

Please help me if I am doing anything wrong or not following the standards.

Here is my source I tried with,

**res\layout\list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/state_list"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Item"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:padding="5dp">

            </TextView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**res\layout\activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**res\animator\state_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="8dp"
            android:valueType="floatType">

        </objectAnimator>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="4dp"
            android:valueType="floatType">

        </objectAnimator>

    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I Think you're looking for this . http://stackoverflow.com/a/30746596/7704356

Comment: @Harisali: Yes right. But  it isn't required to create all the stufff provided in your link. Android itself provides elevation, shadows and animation using the material design standards from android L and above.
 I am following the material design concept. But its not working despite doing all these things I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ResyclerView in `list_item.xml` is not clickable as default.

and in the `state_list.xml` `android:state_pressed= "true"` will not trigger.

so the solution is just adding the `android:clickable="true"` to the RecyclerView of  `list_item.xml`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try using CardView?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/item_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Item"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:padding="5dp">

            </TextView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But I need to know how I can achieve the same using the existing code. There should be some standards to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use cardview as a RecyclerviewList Item. 
[Card View example](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

It has app:cardElevation property that can give you desired effect.